# Reliable way to burn VIDEO_TS folder on a DVD?

Tags: video, digital-recording, software-recommendation

I'm building a video dvd for a wedding. I have rendered the VIDEO_TS and AUDIO_TS folders using an authoring software. 
I have burned them into a DVD using Windows, but the DVD is unreadable on 3 different dvd players, so I can suppose I have made something wrong.

What else do I need to have a working DVD?

Comment: What type of DVD disk are you using?  Some DVD players work better with DVD+R or DVD-R disks.  The specs for the DVD player usually show what types of disks they are compatible with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the proper formatting for it to be read by a DVD player that only reads standards compliant disks.  Specifically, DVD Video disks use the UDF 1.02 format.

Comment: Using a proper burning software I fixed the issue, setting the UDF format. Thanks!